# Register a complete JMS configuration in runtime using Spring

Tags: spring-jms

How can I create all beans necessary to subscribe a JMS topic from another application?

My application can be integrated with another one, for this to happen my application must to subscribe to the JMS topic after the application startup. And so to be able to unsubscribe in runtime. The JMS configurations like **broker url**, **user** and **password** must be configured by a administrator and I need to do this (reconfigure the JMS) without stop/start my application.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the connection factory and message listener container objects programmatically.

Be sure to call `afterPropertiesSet()` on the container before `start()` ing it.

See [DefaultMessageListenerContainer not receiving messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21360550/defaultmessagelistenercontainer-not-receiving-messages/21364885#21364885)